# how to change the color of an individual pixel in uiimage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a UIImage which is an image of a mountainous landscape. I need to show locations on this image, by turning corresponding 2-3 pixels at the spot to red. How do I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw image to graphics context like this:

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//Save current status of graphics context
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);
```

And then just draw a point on it wherever you want like this:

```
//CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x,y,1,1));
//Fix error according to @gsempe's comment
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x,y,1./(image.scale),1./(image.scale)))
```

Then just save it to UIImage again:

```
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

You also should take care of image's orientation. [Here](http://trandangkhoa.blogspot.ru/2009/07/iphone-os-drawing-image-and-stupid.html) is some good article on it.

Comment: This code will draw a {2,2} sized rectangle on retina display. To draw only one point you should call CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x,y,1./(image.scale),1./(image.scale)))

Comment: Where we are setting actually new color for pixel? please explain.

Comment: @AvinashJadhav call to CGContextFillRect does that. Draws a rectangle of size 1x1 at (x,y)